# robot_localization with imu and encoder shaking odom->base transform

Tags: gazebo, navigation, robot-localization, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i am using robot_localization to merge imu and wheel encoder data and want it to publish the odom->base_footprint (2d projection of base_link) transform. I configured everything so far, but the transform starts to shake more and more the further the robot drives away from the start-point. The entire robot is simulated in gazebo.

The problem is very simillar to [290160](https://answers.ros.org/question/290160/robot-localization-erratic-behavior-gps-imu-odometry/) but it seems like the original author hasn't found a solution either back in 2018.

I would be thankful if anyone can help me out here.

EDIT: i just found out that gazebo is still publishing the odom transform even though i set the parameter publishOdom of the differential plugin to false. I only found this by refreshing my tf tree very fast and saw gazebo as the publisher every now and then.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372292/robot_localization-with-imu-and-encoder-shaking-odom-%3Ebase-transform/) by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) on ROS Answers with karma: 220 on 2021-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After realizing this problem is caused by Gazebo and not by robot_localization i found out that the problem is caused by an error in the gazebo tutorials here [Gazebo tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins).
In the differential drive plugin section the parameter is written as publishOdom but it needs to be publishOdomTF.

I know that this now transitioned to a gazebo related question and/or answer and should be over at the gazebo forum but still want the information to be somewhere.

---

Originally posted by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) with karma: 220 on 2021-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1